# Javascript prototype between two objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If i have doctor object , patient object and a Exam(with few different exams functions inside object). How can I write
Doctor(john) is examining with that type of exam that patient ? In advanced im sorry if i wasn't clear about my question..

Ive tried this .

```
Exam.prototype.John = function(Doctor){
    return this.bloodPresure();
}
```

Comment: can you show definition code of "doctor object , patient object and a Exam"?

Comment: You probably need to pass instances of doctor and patient to the exam instance. Or are you looking for natural language like `drJohn().is().examing('blood pressure').of().pxFred()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Doctor {

Comment: that's Ok, mr. patient ) . So how about the definition code?

Comment: Doesn't sound like the `prototype` should be involved at all here. All three types of objects represent entirely different things, so nothing of their definition (including the `prototype`), should share anything. Just the instances of these objects should interact, e.g. `drJohn.examine(examination, patient)`.

Comment: Sorry man storm made electricity shutdown when i wanted to edit :)var `var Doctor = {
 name: this.name,
 lastName : this.lastName,
 speciality : this.speciality
 ExamApointment: function(Patijent)
 {
  return Patient;
 }
}

var Patient = {
 name : this.name,
 lastName : this.lastName,
 id : this.id,
 cardNumber: this.cardNumber

 chooseDoctor: function(Doctor)
 {
  this.chooseDoctor = Doctor; 
  
 }
}

var exam = {
 Doctor = this.Doctor,
 Patient = this.Patient,

 function type1(param1,param2,Patient){

 }

function type2(param1,param2,Patient){

 }

function type3(param1,param2,Patient){

 }`

Answer (score 0):

- Find a pattern from a reliable source: [MDN - Prototype - Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples)
- Then apply relevant content to code.
- Just by going through this example step by step, I learned something.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Define Doctor constructor
var Doctor = function() {
  this.proscribe = true;
};

// Add intruct method to Doctor.prototype
Doctor.prototype.instruct = function() {
  if (this.proscribe) {
    console.log('Proscription filled by ' + this.name + ' Do not operate heavy machinery');
  }
};

// Define the generalPractioner constructor
var generalPractitioner = function(name, title) {
  Doctor.call(this);
  this.name = name;
  this.title = title;
};

// Create a generalPractitioner.prototype object that inherits from Doctor.prototype.
generalPractitioner.prototype = Object.create(Doctor.prototype);
generalPractitioner.prototype.constructor = generalPractitioner;

// Instantiate instruct method
generalPractitioner.prototype.instruct = function() {
  if (this.proscribe) {
    console.log('Proscribed by ' + this.title + this.name + '  Do not operate heavy machinery');
  }
};

// Define the Pharmacist constructor
var Pharmacist = function(name) {
  Doctor.call(this);
  this.name = name;
};

// Create a Pharmacist.prototype object that inherits from Doctor.prototype.
Pharmacist.prototype = Object.create(Doctor.prototype);
Pharmacist.prototype.constructor = Pharmacist;

// Define the Intern constructor
var Intern = function(name) {
  Doctor.call(this);
  this.name = name;
  this.proscribe = false;
};

// Create a Intern.prototype object that inherits from Doctor.prototype.
Intern.prototype = Object.create(Doctor.prototype);
Intern.prototype.constructor = Intern;

// Usage
var john = new generalPractitioner('John', 'Dr.');
var mike = new Pharmacist('Mike');
var ann = new generalPractitioner('Ann', 'Dr.');
var vick = new Pharmacist('Vick');
var intern = new Intern('Intern');

john.instruct();
// Proscribed by Dr. John Do not operate heavy machinery'

mike.instruct();
// Proscription filled by Mike Do not operate heavy machinery'

ann.instruct();
// Proscribed by Dr. Ann Do not operate heavy machinery'

vick.instruct();
// Proscription filled by Vick Do not operate heavy machinery'

intern.instruct();
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```